# How to automatically exit out of jdb using python

Tags: java, debugging, jdwp

I'm trying to run jdb via python3.

```
test = subprocess.check_output(['jdb','-attach','localhost:1234'])
```

But it's stuck there because it is waiting for an input.

Is there a way to exit automatically?